# Unrecognized runtime "julia"; defaulting to "python3"

Tags: julia, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run [the Julia template in Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb), but the first code block throws the following warning:

*Unrecognized runtime "julia"; defaulting to "python3"*

Google search didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the popup *Unrecognized runtime "julia"; defaulting to "python3"*.

When you start, it opens a connection to a machine.   julia is not installed on the machine.  The first cell starts with '%%shell' to tell jupyter to feed the rest of the cell to the command 'shell'.  The rest of the first cell are a series of shell commands that install julia.

This script that installs julia can take a while.  When I just tried it, it ran for over 4 minutes.  It has several "Installing ..." progress messages, but 3:30 of the wait was after it said "Installing Julia package Plots...".  Eventually the output (white area below the gray cell that starts with '%%shell') should say something like the text that was there before it started:

> Installing Julia 1.7.1 on the current Colab Runtime...
> 2022-05-12 01:19:55 URL:https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.7/julia-1.7.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz [123374573/123374573] -> "/tmp/julia.tar.gz" [1]
> Installing Julia package IJulia...
> Installing Julia package BenchmarkTools...
> Installing Julia package Plots...
>    *(long delay here)*
> Installing IJulia kernel...
> [ Info: **Installing julia kernelspec in /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.7**
> **Successfully installed julia version 1.7.1!**
> **Please reload this page (press Ctrl+R, ⌘+R, or the F5 key) then**
> **jump to the 'Checking the Installation' section.**

If you've waited much longer than 5 minutes and it hasn't completed, maybe try disconnecting (menu "Runtime" > "Disconnect and delete runtime"), refresh, and start the first cell again.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Found this on Julia's discourse forum (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-run-julia-in-google-colab/43169)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).